# Which SQLite.Net.Attributes to ignore object field as Column?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, sqlite-net

I am using Sqlite in Universal Windows with **SQLite.Net-PCL** and I wrote a class for later table creation:

```
[Table("my_tab")]
    public class MyObj
    {
        [PrimaryKey, Column("column1")]
        public string myObjField1 { get; set; }

        [Column("column2")]
        public string myObjField2 { get; set; }

        //???
        public string myObjField3 { get; set; }
    }
```

My question is how to ignore `myObjField3` to be as a table column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can just use `[Ignore]`atribute, so it should look like:

```
 [Table("my_tab")]
    public class MyObj
    {
        [PrimaryKey, Column("column1")]
        public string myObjField1 { get; set; }

        [Column("column2")]
        public string myObjField2 { get; set; }

        [Ignore]
        public string myObjField3 { get; set; }
    }
```

Simple enough, right? :)