# SQLite datamodel, preventing column from writing to or reading from DB

Tags: sqlite, maui

I'm working on a .net Maui application where I need to have a few columns added to the model that are used for application / control tracking but should not be stored in the DB.

This is an example of a data model I am using:

```
[Table("CheckListItem")]
public class CheckListItem
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(CheckList))]
    public int checkListID { get; set; }
    public string itemText { get; set; }
    public bool isChecked { get; set; }
    public bool isSkipped { get; set; }
    public int itemOrder { get; set; }

    [ManyToOne]
    public CheckList CheckList { get; set; }

    public (bool IsValid, string ErrorMessage) Validate()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(itemText))
        {
            return (false, $"{nameof(itemText)} is required.");
        }
        return (true, null);
    }
}
```

I'd like to add in a couple of columns like:

```
bool isBeingDragged
bool isDropped
```

But again, I don't want them to write to the DB.

I'd like to stay away from loading the objects, populating new objects to use, then going back to the DB objects.  That would be one way to do that... But it's a lot of code.

Is there an option like this?

```
[NoDB] 
bool isBeingDragged;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which SQLite.Net.Attributes to ignore object field as Column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214341/which-sqlite-net-attributes-to-ignore-object-field-as-column)

Comment: As a summary, I will post an answer so that it will help others who have similar problems. . :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[Ignore]` attribute to achieve this, just as Jason mentioned.

please refer to the following code:

```
   [Ignore] 
   bool isBeingDragged;
```